# CountVectorizer does not process my text data. It keep giving me AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, attributeerror, countvectorizer

I have created process_textData function that takes in a pandas DataFrame column of text, then performs the following:
1. Convert text to lower case and remove all punctuation
2. Optionally apply stemming
3. Apply Ngram Tokenisation
4. Returns the tokenised text as a list.

```
import string
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
from nltk import everygrams, word_tokenize
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

def process_text(data, n=1):
    stemmer = SnowballStemmer('english')
    data = data.apply(lambda x: x.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)))
    data = data.apply(lambda x: [' '.join(ng).lower() for ng in everygrams(word_tokenize(x),n,n)])
    data = data.apply(lambda x: [stemmer.stem(word) for word in x])
    return data
```

After that I implement the function into Sklearn CountVectorizer and it give me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'.
```

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer(stop_words=None, ngram_range=(3, 3))
X = cv.fit_transform(process_textData(df.news, n=3))
X.toarray()
```

What am I doing wrong, Can somebody help with this?

Comment: can you paste a sample data?

Answer (score 0):

This returns a list of lists:

```py
    # ...
    data = data.apply(lambda x: [' '.join(ng).lower() for ng in everygrams(word_tokenize(x),n,n)])
    data = data.apply(lambda x: [stemmer.stem(word) for word in x])
    return data
```

While `fit_transform` expects a list of strings. I suggest editing as such:

```py
    # ...
    data = data.apply(lambda x: ''.join([' '.join(ng).lower() for ng in everygrams(word_tokenize(x),n,n)]))
    data = data.apply(lambda x: ''.join([stemmer.stem(word) for word in x]))
    return data
```

Comment: Happy to help :) If your problem is solved, would you mark my answer as accepted?

Comment: Sure thing! All done! Thanks again!